# JMAP command and error of debuggee is 64 bit

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, jmap

I need heap dump of the web logic server that's running on IST environment. I don't have access to that so I have asked support team to do that. The command that's executed is as following on UNIX:

**./jmap -heap:format=b 19153**

When support team executes the command, they get below output:

Attaching to process ID 19153, please wait...
Error attaching to process:Attach failed : debuggee is 64 bit, use java -d64 for debugger

I think server is 64 bit, but what this suggestion is saying? Does it mean the server should be started with that flag in the command?

I tried to look for such issue on Internet, but I get nothing useful. Do any one has idea how to get to the solution!!!???

I thank you all for extending your kind help!

Regards,
Ketan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're using jmap command from the same path (directory) as used to run process 19153. For me it seams that there are more than one JDK installed on host, one is used to run process 19153 and other to invoke jmap.

You can check java version using: `java -version`

Do you use `-d64` JVM parameter to start process 19153?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ragnor.

I just had to add -d64 in the command.

```
./jmap -d64 -heap:format=b 19153
```

As JVM is 64 bit so had to do this!